# aligned_alloc memory block in a copy assignment constructor crashes while being freed

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, memory-alignment

I am maintaining some legacy code which was missing a copy assignment constructor in a managed Aligned Pointer class. I added one as follows (simplified view):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <class T, unsigned AlignB> 
class AlignedPtr {
private:
    T *mpBlock;
    unsigned mBlkSize;
public:
    // Size specific Ctor
    AlignedPtr(unsigned uNum) : 
    mpBlock(static_cast<T*>  (aligned_alloc(uNum*sizeof(T),  AlignB))),
    mBlkSize(uNum) {}
    // Default, empty Ctor
    AlignedPtr(void) : mpBlock(nullptr), mBlkSize(0) {}
    // Copy Assignment Ctor
    AlignedPtr& operator=(const AlignedPtr& x)
    {
        T *mpNewBlock(static_cast<T*>(aligned_alloc(x.mBlkSize*sizeof(T), AlignB)));
        for (size_t index=0; index < x.mBlkSize; index++) {
            mpNewBlock[index] = x.mpBlock[index];
        }
        free(mpBlock);
        mpBlock  = mpNewBlock;
        mBlkSize = x.mBlkSize;
        return *this;
    }
    // Destroy managed pointer
    ~AlignedPtr() {
        free(mpBlock);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    AlignedPtr<float, 16> first_ptr;
    std::cout << "Pointer Initialized" << std::endl;

    first_ptr = AlignedPtr<float, 16>(8);
    std::cout << "Pointer Re-initialized" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My expectation was that the program will terminate normally, however I saw AlignedPtr Dtor fail when *first_ptr* goes out of scope (main termination). 
I compile above without any optimizations as:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g aligned_alloc_bug.cpp -o aab
```

On a Ubuntu 14.04 with g++ 4.8.2 and get the following run-time error:

```
Pointer Initialized
Pointer Re-initialized
*** Error in `./aab': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000001cf9080 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Interestingly when I replace *aligned_alloc* with *malloc* or *posix_memalign* for that matter program terminates correctly. Is this a bug in *aligned_alloc* or am I missing something basic?

P.S: 1) I did a brief search for a gcc bug which returned false. 2) Advise to avoid managing raw pointers is acknowledged in advance but I would appreciate any help for the problem at hand.

Comment: Did you follow the Rule of Three?

Comment: @Kerrek SB I did, complete program has a custom copy constructor as well.

Comment: I think it is because in assignment operator you are reading at 4 byte boundary, but the memory is allocated at 16 bytes, it is expected the read will be at 16 byte boundary.
Please try and use valgrind for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the arguments to `aligned_alloc` in the wrong order, ["documentation"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc).

> void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size);

This then results in memory corruption, which is only detected when you call `free`.

Also, you should consider implementing a copy constructor. Here is a simple implementation:

```
AlignedPtr(const AlignedPtr& x) { *this = x; }
```

Comment: I realized that but thanks for the answer, gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have two objects pointing to the same memory: the anonymous object and the first_ptr after the assignment operator completed have the same address. When their respective destructors get called..... you can probably guess what is going to happen.

Comment: since I allocate new memory in copy assignment I don't think my objects are pointing to same memory. Having said that I have done a more basic mistake i.e. using the incorrect arguments order for aligned_alloc function. I wrongly assumed that aligned_alloc has same signature as WIN32 aligned_malloc. What a miss it was....